# Scala Maps getOrElseUpdate and Append result

Tags: scala

I have a Map which looks like this

```
var map = Map[Int, Map[Int, Int]]()
```

I need the functionality where I need to lookup values in the inner map and if the value is found the result is "added" and not just updated.

I have written this code like

```
map.get(x) match {
  case Some(innerMap) => 
      innerMap.get(y) match {
        case Some(z) => map(x)(y) = z + a
        case None => map(x)(y) = z
  case None => map(x) = Map(y -> a)
```

If you pass the inputs `x=2,y=2,a=10` and `x=2,y=2,a=10` to the code above the map will contain `x=2,y=2,a=20` because values are added.

But I don't like this nested pattern matching. (reminds me of the nested ifs) I tried to simplify this using `getOrElseUpdate`

```
 map
   .getOrElseUpdate(x, Map(y -> a))
   .getOrElseUpdate(y, a)
```

This is good but doesn't handle the scenario where y in found in the inner map and we needed to do a `z + a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily the most efficient solution, but simple - you can instantiate values with zeroes, and then *add* the value itself assuming all the keys are already there:

```
map
  .getOrElseUpdate(x, Map(y -> 0))
  .getOrElseUpdate(y, 0)
map(x)(y) += a
```